# Jena:union merge the same graph?

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web

When i merge using union, there is a case that two identical rdf exist in the same file.
How can i remove identical rdf in the file?

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

import java.io.*;

public class simplesameunion {

static final String inputFileName1 = "vc-db-3.rdf";    
static final String inputFileName2 = "vc-db-3.rdf";

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    // create an empty model
    Model model1 = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    Model model2 = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

    // use the class loader to find the input file
    InputStream in1 = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName1);
    if (in1 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + inputFileName1 + " not found");
    }
    InputStream in2 = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName2);
    if (in2 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + inputFileName2 + " not found");
    }        

    // read the RDF/XML files
    model1.read( in1, "" );
    model2.read( in2, "" );             
    // merge the graphs
    Model model = model1.union(model2);
    // print the graph as RDF/XML
    model.write(new PrintWriter(System.out));
    System.out.println();       
    }
}
```

The result of the code is as follows.

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:vcard="http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://somewhere/JohnSmith/">
    <vcard:N rdf:nodeID="A0"/>
    <vcard:FN>John Smith</vcard:FN>
    <vcard:N rdf:nodeID="A1"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="A0">
    <vcard:Family>Smith</vcard:Family>
    <vcard:Given>John</vcard:Given>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="A1">
    <vcard:Family>Smith</vcard:Family>
    <vcard:Given>John</vcard:Given>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

The Literal value of RDF is repeated. This is because the values of the blank nodes are different.
How can i merge without overlapping values?